# How do I make ABPeoplePicker start at the top each time it opens?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, abpeoplepickerview

When ABPeoplePicker first loads, it starts at the top of your address book with the search bar displayed at the top. However, once the user interacts with it, it loads to the point where it was last scrolled to. Is there a command or property to make it always load so that the search bar at the top shows?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
// Show the people picker
[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:YES];

// Force display the search bar and make the keyboard pop up
[self.picker.topViewController.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
[self.picker.topViewController.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```